# why isn't this finger stick antibody test (for covid) in more common use?

Tags: covid-19, test

I had some concerns about going to the dentist, because dental treatment involves a lot of aerosolized droplets and seems like a good way to get a high dose of covid.

My dentist's office (in Manhattan) told me:

> We are testing every patient and healthcare worker in our facility via Rapid Finger stick antibody test. This test can be comfortably performed in our office just prior to your appointment. The test results appear in 10 minutes, after which patients may remove their face covering and receive dental treatment. *Please allow 15 extra minutes for your appointment*

On the one hand, that's really great!

On the other hand, it's surprising that this is the first I've heard of a ten-minute finger stick antibody test.  If the test is really this great, why isn't everybody doing this constantly?

Are there false positive or false negative issues with this test?  Is it too expensive for common use?

Comment: Have you considered who is actually at risk from all those aerosols? The dentists and hygienists should be wearing a mask, so you're relatively safe from them. It's they who are in danger from you.

Comment: I'm not worried about the dentists but I am worried about the other patients.